# Set of Rotation Matrices in $R^n$ Which Fix (1,1,…,1)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, linear-transformations, orthogonal-matrices

For the case where $n=3$, I was given these rotation matrices which fix the vector $(1,1,1)$.

[image]

How would I generalize these matrices for $R^n$?

Comment: I suppose you're looking for $n \times n$ orthogonal matrices with determinant $1$ which have an eigenvalue $1$ with corresponding eigenvector $(1,1,\dots, 1)$?

Comment: @NullSimplex There are multiple things that you potentially could have in mind when you say that you want to "generalize these matrices". Does kipf's comment describe what you are looking for, or is there some other property that you want these matrices to have?

Comment: @kipf That is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select any two length-1 and orthonormal unit (column-) vectors $u$ and $v$ such that $u$ and $v$ are both orthogonal to $(1,1,\dots,1)$. For any angle $\theta$, the matrix
$$
M = I + \pmatrix{u & v}\pmatrix{(\cos \theta - 1) & -\sin \theta\\
 \sin \theta  & (\cos \theta - 1)}\pmatrix{u & v}^T\\
= I + (\cos \theta - 1)(uu^T + vv^T) + \sin \theta(vu^T - uv^T)
$$
represents a rotation within $n$-dimensional space that fixes the vector $(1,1,\dots,1)$. In particular, this rotation occurs within the plane spanned by $u$ and $v$, which importantly is orthogonal to $(1,1,\dots,1)$.

Keep in mind, however, that for "rotations" in $n$-dimensional space with $n \geq 4$, it is possible to have multiple simultaneous rotations in mutually orthogonal planes. This transformation only applies a transformation in a single 2-d plane.

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  If I wanted to change the eigenvector from (1,1,…,1) to $v\neq0$, would I change $I$ to the diagonal matrix $D$ whose element $d_{i,i} = v_i$ and change $cos(\theta)-1$ to $cos(\theta)-v_i$?  This question is not as important, just curious what the general formula is.

Comment: @Null No, you would still keep the identity matrix there. The change is that $u$ and $v$ should be orthogonal to this new vector instead

Comment: Last reply, just making sure.  So the $cos(\theta)-1$ would also be preserved?  The only difference is that $u$ and $v$ would be orthogonal to this new vector, but otherwise your original response stays the same?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right